# Unresolved reference: showToast in Kotlin

Tags: android, tensorflow, kotlin

I am trying to use tensorflow lite version in android. I got the following error while building the project. Please help.

> Error

```
Unresolved reference: showToast
```

> Code

```
override fun onConfigureFailed(session: CameraCaptureSession) {
                    this@MainActivity.showToast("Failed")
```

Answer (score 0):

use this line to show toast

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this line to show toast in a fragment.

```
Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Authentication failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you didn't make a `showToast` function yet, but tried to use it. That's why `Android Studio` doesn't recognize what `showToast` is.(Unresolved reference: showToast)

#### Make a `showToast` function first.

ex)

```kotlin
fun showToast(message: String) {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).